# I am having issue with my contact form for my Magento website

Tags: forms, magento, contacts

I have set a contact form in Magento and it is not working please help.  The URL is http://v4vintage.com/magento/contact-us-email.

Regards,

Jay

Comment: Your submit button does not do anything: Tested in I.E 10. What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: Hi James, I want to click on the submit button and the form (fields filled in) will be sent to my email address. I am new to this and I know I have done something wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://blog.decryptweb.com/form-in-magento/) page to learn how to `POST` form data, and [this](http://dbhoopendra.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/how-to-send-email-in-magento.html) one to actually grab the form data and send an email.

Comment: I have changed my email contact us form http://v4vintage.com/magento/index.php/contact_us_eg/?___store=default and it is not working, please help.  When you click submit it does not send to me email address.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your page, it has many forms. Kindly check the score-code and use a single form.